# Mysql increment column value by group

Tags: mysql

Would like to increment column between groups of the same parentid. See problem below:

```
ID    Name    Parent   Pos
================================
1     Alex       1      0
2     Mary       1      0
3     John       1      0
4     Doe        2      0
5     Bob        2      0
6     Kate       2      0
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
ID    Name    Parent   Pos
================================
1     Alex       1      1
2     Mary       1      2
3     John       1      3
4     Doe        2      1
5     Bob        2      2
6     Kate       2      3
```

I would do this using two queries to **select distinct values** of the parent, then do a loop and **update** in sets but I feel there is a more efficient way!!

Answer (score 4):

These problems can be easily solved by ranking function. As mysql doesn't support ranking function we've to go with alternative. 
Check this query

-- for dense rank

```
SELECT 
  Id,
  NAME,
  Parent,
  Pos
  , case when @previousParent = rankTab.Parent THEN @runningGroup := @runningGroup + 1
         else @runningGroup := 1 AND @previousParent := rankTab.Parent 
    END as denseRank

FROM
  inc_col_val_by_group AS rankTab,
    (SELECT @runningGroup := 0) AS b 
  , (select @previousParent := 0 ) as prev
ORDER BY rankTab.Parent -- order by Parent 

--  

    -- -- below are the create table & insert the given records script
    -- create the table
    CREATE TABLE inc_col_val_by_group
    (Id INT
    , NAME CHAR(10)
    , Parent INT
    , Pos INT
    )

    -- insert some records
    INSERT INTO inc_col_val_by_group(Id, NAME, Parent, Pos)
    VALUES
    (1, 'Alex', 1, 0)
    , (1, 'Mary', 1, 0)
    , (3, 'John', 1, 0)
    , (4, 'Doe', 2, 0)
    , (5, 'Bob', 2, 0)
    , (6, 'Kate', 2, 0)
```

Comment: inc_col_val_by_group ??

Comment: [inc_col_val_by_group] is the table name that I've created to work on your problem statement. (create, insert scripts are already included in the above answer)

Comment: Doesn't work!! I want the positions to be incremental. see the expected result!!

Comment: ok, you want ranking inside the group (dense rank).. I updated the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to probably use variables:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@p = parent, @p + 1,
                  if(@p := parent, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as pos
from table t cross join
     (select @p := 0, @rn := 0) init
order by parent, id;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your query but the increments were not sequential. See http://pbrd.co/1MCMoC6

Comment: @AlexanderKimaru . . . That is because the query mistakenly had `group by`instead of `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @posn:=0;
SET @pid:=0;

SELECT  IF(@pid=k.parentid,@posn:=@posn+1,@posn:=1) pos,@pid:=k.parentid pid, k.* 
FROM kids k 
ORDER BY parentid
```